# Why is my static CSS file working fine but not javascipt in Django?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, web-deployment

I'm new to Django. I'm trying to add a javascript for my navbar. Browser is reading static CSS file properly. But it looks like browser is ignoring my static javascript file. Here is my code:

**Settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
```

**Index.html**

```
<html lang="en">

{% load static %}

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href="{% static 'style.css' %}">
    <script type='text/javascript' src="{% static 'style.js' %}"></script>
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock title %}</title>
</head>
```

To check whether javascript is working properly I have only put a alert box. But still it is not showing alert box.

**style.js**

```
alert("Checking");
```

Comment: Is your `style.js` actually downloading by the browser with status code 200? Check it in "network" tab in devtools in the browser (opens by F12).

Comment: If your code runs on a web server, have you run collectstatic after creating the js file?

Comment: @yagus ..... Yes..i have already tried collectstatic...but problem remains same..

Comment: @SergeiMinaev
Yes...i style.js file is downloading with status code 200....